# How to convert bracket arrays into brace arrays via PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I like to know how to convert bracket arrays into brace arrays via PHP.

This means to convert this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

to this:

```
[{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}]
```

additionally, I like to know if we can add key to all the values in the brace arrays. This means to convert this:

```
[{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}]
```

to this:

```
[
{"index":1},
{"index":2},
{"index":3},
{"index":4},
{"index":5}
]
```

And then, I like to know if we can merge multiple brace arrays. This means to merge this:

```
[
{"index":1},
{"index":2},
{"index":3},
{"index":4},
{"index":5}
]
```

and this:

```
[
{"value":"Apple"},
{"value":"Orange"},
{"value":"Pearl"},
{"value":"Gold"},
{"value":"Pig"}
]
```

into this:

```
[
{"index":1, "value":"Apple"},
{"index":2 ...
{"index":5, "value":"Pig"}
]
```

Thanks!

Here are one of my attempts so far:

```
$directories = array_map('basename', glob('./path/folders/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
$temp = array_fill_keys($directories, 'name');
$api = array_flip($temp);
```

Of course the code above didn't work because it does not separate array keys into objects.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far and then give a concrete problem you're having. This community is not here to give you a full-out tutorial

Comment: Just added an example.

Comment: This question reminds me of the example given in [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Excellent question, but I don't think PHP can do the convertion. It requires you to create brace arrays from the beginning if you would like to use it later. Of course I might be wrong.

Comment: Sure, that might be true. Do you think you can solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512796/how-could-i-reorganize-json-arrays-and-give-key-string-to-each-key-while-arrayin/28514416?noredirect=1#comment45354623_28514416

Comment: No, I can't. It's beyond me, but I would like to know as well.

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to manipulate JSON.  I suggest that you use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse serialised JSON into PHP data structures; and then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to serialise your manipulated structures back into JSON.

Comment: There is no such thing as a _“brace array”_. What you _mean_ seems to be an array of objects, instead of an array of single numbers. But I am voting to close as a duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512796/how-could-i-reorganize-json-arrays-and-give-key-string-to-each-key-while-arrayin, because this seems to be what this is really about.

Comment: @eggyal It sounds hopeful. Do you think you can write up an example on how to use decode and encode?

Comment: @AeroWindwalker: Are the examples on the manual pages to which I linked no good?

Comment: @AeroWindwalker, look at this: http://eiskis.net/baseline-php/read/arrays. You can find a lot of interesting array manipulation functions.

Comment: @eggyal wait, you confused me for a second. Is that why json_decode(array_map('basename', glob('./path/folders/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR))) would return error? How should I specify this command?

Comment: @FilipKrstic yeah man, I read it through and it seems like array_flatten might be remotely useful for the conversation. I am not certain how to use it for the conversation though.

Comment: Dude this is like four questions in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only to answer the first question, and not really a perfect solution, but hopefully it helps.

array_chunk($your_array, 1);

This would output your first array into:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

Not quite what you asked for, but I think it's better than nothing.

PS. I don't think PHP can do the conversion between bracket and brace arrays. It requires you to create brace arrays from the beginning if you would like to use it later. Of course I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understood your questions clearly and I don't know on what project you doing. This is solution for your questions as I understood them. Next code is fully commented, step by step.

```
<?php

/* 
* Answer 1
* You have this: [1,2,3,4,5]
* You want this: [{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}]
*
*/

$something = array(1,2,3,4,5); //  Elements inside are integers

// Brace it
$braced_something = array(); // Elements inside will bestrings
foreach($something as $value)
{
    $braced_something[] = "{" . $value . "}";
}

// Result:
var_dump($braced_something);

// If your final result is JSON object
$json = json_encode($braced_something);
var_dump($json);

/* 
* Answer 1 (addition question)
* You have this: ["{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}","{5}"]
* You want this: [{"index":1},{"index":2},{"index":3},{"index":4},{"index":5}]
* 
*/
$some_json = '["{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}","{5}"]';

// Decode JSON object
$some_json_decoded = json_decode($some_json);

// Result of decoding
var_dump($some_json_decoded);

// Add "index" identifier
$new_some = array();
foreach($some_json_decoded as $value)
{
    $value = str_replace(array( '{', '}' ), '', $value);
    $new_some[] = array("index" => (int)$value); // Explicit conversion of string to int
}

/* If you don't convert string to int, numbers will be under "" in JSON object.
There is another solution to leave value as string and call json_encode like this json_encode($new_some, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).
JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK will delete "" before transformation of array to JSON object. */

// Result:
var_dump($new_some);

// If your final result is JSON object
$json_some = json_encode($new_some);
var_dump($json_some);


/* 
* Answer 2
* You have this: [{"index":1},{"index":2},{"index":3},{"index":4},{"index":5}]
* You have this: [{"value":"Apple"},{"value":"Orange"},{"value":"Pearl"},{"value":"Gold"},{"value":"Pig"}]
* You want this: [{"index":1, "value":"Apple"},{"index":2 ... {"index":5, "value":"Pig"}]
*/

// First JSON object
$json_index = '[
{"index":1},
{"index":2},
{"index":3},
{"index":4},
{"index":5}
]';

// Second JSON object
$json_values = '[
{"value":"Apple"},
{"value":"Orange"},
{"value":"Pearl"},
{"value":"Gold"},
{"value":"Pig"}
]';

// Decode JSON objects
$index_decoded = json_decode($json_index);
$values_decoded = json_decode($json_values);

// Result of decoding
var_dump($index_decoded);
var_dump($index_decoded);

// Transform first object to array
$array_index = array();
foreach($index_decoded as $value)
{
    $array_index[] = $value->index;
}

// Result of first transformation
var_dump($array_index);

// Same for second JSON object
$array_values = array();
foreach($values_decoded as $value)
{
    $array_values[] = $value->value;
}
// Result of second transformation
var_dump($array_values);

// Merge two arrays into one array and format as you wanted
$new_array = array();
foreach($array_index as $key => $value)
{
    $new_array[] = array("index" => $value, "value:" => $array_values[$key]);  
}
// Result of merging
var_dump($new_array);

// If your final result is JSON object
$new_json = json_encode($new_array);
var_dump($new_json);
```

**EDIT:** On second answer, I done it as you asked, but note that lenghts of arrays should be same. If they don't, you need to find out how to deal with it. There are multiple ways to do that.